# Yes or No on combobox foreach - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, combobox, html-select

I try to make combobox/html-select tag for my CodeIgniter apps.

**for field value 'IsYes' on my table :**

> If I select Yes the value based on variable and if No the value is 0.

**for field value 'IsNo' on my table :**

> If I select Yes the value is 0 and if No the value based on variable.

**Here's my view code:**

```html
<td align="center">                   
      <select name="YesNo[]">                 
        <option value="<?php echo $list2_1b_1b->Value;?>">Yes</option>
        <option value="<?php echo $list2_1b_1b->Value;?>">No</option>
      </select>
    </td>
```

**my controller look like this :**

```
$WSDetailID     = $this->input->post('WSDetailID[]');
$YesNo          = $this->input->post('YesNo[]');
$data = array();

$index = 0; 
foreach($WSDetailID as $datanis)
{ 
    array_push($data, array(
    'WSDetailID'    =>$datanis,
    'IsYes'         =>$YesNo[$index],   
    'IsNo'          =>$YesNo[$index],
    ));

    $index++;
}
```

Comment: If you want to use php only for that and not JS then you have to create a form and a submit button. PHP can not recognize the DOM changes unless you "submit" your form.

Comment: what should I look for DOM on javascript ? i need keyword for solve my issue...